# On the mobile version of the page there is a white line on the right side

Tags: html, css

There is a white line on the right side

[image]

First, I tried to set up

```
section{
    width: 100%;
}
```

then

```
@media (max-width:420px){
    section{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Didn't help.
Link for full code:  https://codepen.io/andrzej-hnatiuk/pen/xxXWYjx
In codepen some pictures won't open, but in VScode they do.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Do you get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your navigation (`<section id=section`) is too wide, which forces to make the page wider as the screen is. The block below does not grow along.

Solution: let your navigation break on multiple lines, or use a hamburger menu. It depends on how you would like your page to look.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your section with #section id. under a specific width size it won't be smaller more, so then content will get smaller and create a white gap on left. 
 you can decrease your font-size on media query for section #section or using wrap flex box to wrap your section #section under a specific width size or another thing like left panel etc.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because the content is overflowing, simply you can add this lines of code and everything will work out.

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}
section,footer{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

here is a new pen [Codepen](https://codepen.io/yherbawi/pen/vYeRrag)